# I have a postgresql setup with 1 master and 2 slaves. Now I want to setup a replication for only one database to reporting server

Tags: postgresql

My problem statements: I can't use bucardo (no approval for creating triggers on prod tables) pglogical only works on Master node.(the publisher). I want to replicate from slave (this is my end goal)

Answer (score 0):

If you have v10 or better, you should definitely use logical replication. The burden on the primary server is minimal.

If for whatever incomprehensible reason you absolutely have to replicate from a standby, you'll have to use streaming replication. Then you have to replicate the whole cluster, but there is no better solution.

One way out could be to put [walbouncer](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/products/walbouncer-enterprise-grade-partial-replication/) in between, which can filter out WAL records for all but one database, so that you ate effectively replicating just one database.

Disclaimer: walbouncer was developed by my company (it is open source though).